# Difference in behavior of CopyImage() API in Windows 7 and Windows 10 for PNG images

Tags: c++, graphics, png, transparency, gdi

Code Snippet:

```
HBITMAP hObject = NULL;
hObject  = (HBITMAP)CopyImage(hObject,         // handle to the image
                         IMAGE_BITMAP,     // type of image to copy
                         m_szImg.cx, m_szImg.cy,  // desired height of new image
                         LR_COPYDELETEORG | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

CBitmap bmp;
bmp.Attach(hObject  );

CDC dcSrc;
dcSrc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

struct
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER header;
    COLORREF col[256];
} bmpi;

ZeroMemory(&bmpi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
bmpi.header.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
GetDIBits(dcSrc, bmp, 0, 0, NULL, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

int nDepth = bmpi.header.biBitCount;

int nSize = bmpi.header.biHeight * ((bmpi.header.biWidth * (nDepth==32 ? 4 : 3) + 3) & ~3);

// get source bitmap data
BYTE* pData = new BYTE[nSize];
GetDIBits(dcSrc, bmp, 0, bmpi.header.biHeight, pData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

In Windows 7 environment->
After GetDIBits function, when I check the memory layout of "pData" in VS 2015, it is laid like "00 00 ff ff 00 00 ff ff 00 00 ff ff" and similar pattern continues.

But in Windows 10 environment, "pData" returns as "00 00 fe fe 00 00 fe fe 00 00 fe fe" and similar pattern continues.
Can somebody point what I am doing wrong here? 
PNG image is same in both the cases.

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  Making an image look good after resizing it is not that simple, Microsoft did tinker with their interpolator algorithm over the years.  Matters a lot on modern hardware with DPI increasing from its once stodgy 96.  Emphasizing a result that's pleasing to the human eye *and* is as efficient as possible.  If you want a more predictable result then you need to use an api that allows you to select the interpolator, nearest-neighbor is the one with the least surprises.

Comment: @Hans, thanks for the info. Just to add, this code works fine for png images of size 16*16, 32*32 and 48*48. I am facing above issue only when image size is 64*64. Let me know if you have some input for this.

Comment: FKI, using StretchBlt() instead of CopyImage() has fixed this issue. Thanks